# epoll/non blocking event driven IO

Tags: epoll, event-driven

My question about epoll based non blocking event driven network IO is this - how does the client connection to the epoll service provider remain open? Why doesn't the connection on the client side die when there isn't a permanent receiver on the server side?

How can the client connection remain open (Keep-Alive on a POST) when the server has processed the request and supposedly moved on.

Comment: Are you talking about [this epoll](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html)? Because if you are, I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: A client can connect to a web server which is driven by epoll and in some cases the client connection can remain open for a long time. How can the client connection remain open (Keep-Alive on a POST) when the server has processed the request and supposedly moved on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong: there still is a permanent receiver on the server side.

Using `epoll`, `select` or plain blocking `read`/`write`s doesn't change anything on the networking side of things. There still is a persistent TCP session (in the case you state). The server process still has a file descriptor open on that connection.
`epoll` is "just" an API that allows the kernel to signal that there is stuff to do on that connection in an efficient, asynchronous manner.

Comment: Ah ... I see. So the burden of number of connections is not removed. The problem still remains as to how many such connection one can open to a machine.

Comment: You are correct, using epoll or not doesn't change the number of connections the server must maintain.